# How to Run Sails in production with pm2 (sails lift --prod) with pm2

Tags: sails.js, production-environment, pm2

How to lift sails in production with pm2 ?? I mean what is the the command of pm2 to get similar action like below command.

```
sails lift --prod
```

like we can run `sails lift` as  `pm2 start app.js`

In pm2 we can specify command line arguments after `--`

I tried `pm2 start app.js -- --prod` to lift sails in production but not working,

How we can achieve this?

Comment: I use `pm2 start app.js -- --prod` and working. What's the error?

Comment: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here Finally I found the correct command for that is like below

```
pm2 start app.js -x -- --prod
```

I went to the all commands of pm2 and found

> -x   --execute-command                 execute a program using fork
>   system

so here this is works fine. Even later I found this command on sails docs too.

[Sails Deployment](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment)

Comment: pm2 3.5.0 doesn't let to run the app in port 80

Comment: for me worked $env:PORT=1337
pm2 start app.js  -- -prod

Answer (score 3):

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js
```